# Размер в пикселях в фотошопе отличается от CSS

Tags: css, html5, photoshop, dpi

Во-первых, я хочу, чтобы вы узнали о DPI / Resolution моего макета.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть макет в фотошопе, с помощью которого я верстаю. Поэтому, когда я пытаюсь установить количество пикселей в `margin-left`, оно отличается от того, которое установлено в макете PSD.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но когда я устанавливаю те же свойства в моем файле .css

```
.header__logo {
  margin-top: 52px;
  margin-left: 300px; <- Expected size
  display: flex;
}
```

Результат отличается. Обратите внимание, что мой проект PSD имеет разрешение 72 DPI.

Comment: если Вы еще замечали, размер шрифта в *PSD* тоже неадекватный. по-моему, это нормально

Comment: Пиксели могут отличатся ещё и на разных устройствах=))) Используйте rem. А для более точной вёрстки скриншоты в помощь.

Comment: А у тебя экран какого разрешения то?